# Why (intuitively) do more charge carriers result in a smaller Hall effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, hall-effect

From the equation for the Hall effect:

$$\Delta V_H= \frac{I B}{n q t}$$

[Where $I$ is the current, $B$ the electric field magnitude, $n$ the density of charge carriers, $q$ the charge per charge carrier, and $t$ is the thickness of the conductor/semiconductor]

I can see  that the more free charge there is (nq), the smaller the Hall voltage. My question is, why would that be the case? Intuitively I would have thought that more charge carriers might result in more charge accumulated on the top and bottom surfaces of the conductor/semiconductor and a higher Hall voltage, rather than a lower Hall voltage.

Comment: *$B$ the electric field magnitude*: You probably mean *$B$ the magnetic field magnitude*.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have higher $n$ (i.e. more free charges per volume).
Then these many charges need to flow only slowly (i.e. with smaller velocity $\mathbf{v}$)
in order to make the same current $I$.

Now the Lorentz-force ($\mathbf{F}=q\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$)
is smaller when you have low velocity $\mathbf{v}$.
And therefore you get a smaller Hall-voltage between the two edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot -  that perfectly answers my question :)